# Dealing with Parentheses in Codeigniter Queries

Tags: php, codeigniter, postgresql, activerecord

I have the following block of code which is expected to return the `count`

```
    $sql = "SELECT sum(count) as count 
            FROM multipleowners WHERE owner = ? " . $localityquery;
    $queryarray = array($owner, $locality);
    $query = $this->db->query($sql, $queryarray);
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
    {
        $result = $query->row_array();
        $count = $result['count']; 
    }
```

But I am getting empty values when i try to print `$count`.

I have used `print_r($this->db->last_query());` and I got the following query,

```
SELECT sum(count) as count FROM multipleowners WHERE owner = 'Davenports Harbour Trustee (2012) Limited' and locality = 'Auckland Central'
```

When I executed this query directly onto my `Postgresql` `IDE` i got the output of `count` as `2`.

What and where could this query be gone wrong ? I doubt the existence of `(` and `)` in the `WHERE` clause. How do I fix this ?

**Update**

When I enabled the profiler I got the following query,

```
SELECT sum(count) as count 
            FROM multipleowners WHERE owner = 'Davenports Harbour Trustee &#40;2012&#41; Limited'  and locality = 'Auckland Central'
```

So obviously the problem exists on the `(` and `)` !!

Comment: The profiler is not at its best in this case.  Try running the query from a sql command prompt and see if the parentheses still give grief.  I doubt they do.

Comment: No I tried running the query on the `IDE` i got the intended output.

Comment: I tried running the query without using query binding and I got the correct output. So that confirms that the issue is with query getting encoded.

Comment: Worth experimenting with mysqli and pdo drivers to see if they are better. - but now I see the postgresql tag. Never mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bingo!! I have added the following line before I passed the variable `$owner` to the query and it worked,

```
$owner = html_entity_decode($owner);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing select sum(db.[count] as icount  because in the language count could be a reserved word as well.  so bracket the field or rename it, try to not name the new output as count..

Comment: That is definitely not the issue here. Thanks for the suggestions though!!